# Socket.IO - How to inform frondEnd when route received data?

Tags: javascript, frontend

For example i have route:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){res.sendFile('C:/Users/.../index.html');});
```

How to inform frondEnd when route received data? I would like show on frondEnd that system received data.

Comment: What does an Express route have to do with `socket.io` and file sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [connect-flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash) middleware.

```
req.flash('success', 'File sent!');
```

or

```
req.flash('error', 'Something went terribly wrong!');
```